# How to let the discord bot send a message that only the sender can see?

Tags: discord.py

How to send a message that only the sender can see in discord.py?

I only allow the sender to view this message from bot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use a component (buttons/selects) or a slash command to send a ephemeral message.

Slash commands are not supported in all versions of discord.py,  and components are suppported in beta 2.0 version of discord.py. Here are some useful examples:
https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/examples/views
You must set the `ephemral` kwarg to `True` when using `Interaction.respond.send_message()`

You must use the following command in your shell to download 2.0:
`pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`

Comment: No problem! You can press the check mark under the downvote button to accept this answer-